# How ensure works in ruby

Tags: ruby

checkout this code and the output

```
def lab
  yield
  ensure
    puts 'in ensure block'
    true
end

puts lab { puts 'inside inline block'; false }

output is
#inside inline block
#in ensure block
#false
```

I was expecting that after the block is executed then ensure will be executed and since ensure returns true , the final output of calling the method would be 'true'.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The ensure block's return value is discarded -- it's just a way to clean up after the function does whatever it's supposed to (and returns the appropriate value). The reason for this is because it allows you to put several `return` statements (or `raise` statements) in different places in the function body, without having to duplicate the cleanup code in different places in the function.

Comment: @Trip: glad you like it -- It's not ruby-specific at all. Most languages with exception handling work the same way (e.g. Java, Python). C++ is an exception to the rule, but there are some even more powerful things you can do with destructors, such as [ScopeGuard](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184403758).

Comment: What if exception does happen in function body? Will the value of the statement in the ensure section become the return value? (My experiments seemed to work this way but I was wondering if this is formally defined in the spec)

Answer (score 14):

See [this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20201109034938/http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2009/11/17/ensure-with-explicit-return.html) for an overview of how `ensure` behaves with both implicit and explicit returns.

Comment: that's a good blog post. But the author did not explicitly mentioned that unless return is mentioned return values are discarded.

Comment: @emkays thanks for the heads up. I've replaced with a link to the Internet Archive where the blog post is still available. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to explicitly return true, `ensure` might just not return the last value automagically.